# React redux using state within an action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to create an action creator with a method that used to be within my component's logic. I understand how to turn it into an action creator; however, I'm not sure how to work around the ternary operator as it relies on something that was coming from the local state. **this.state.searchTerm** as well as **this.state.data.currentPage** is needed for the code to work the way I need it to work.

```
export const loadMoreMovies = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        const searchEndpoint = `${SEARCH_BASE_URL}${this.state.searchTerm}&page=${this.state.data.currentPage + 1}`;
        const popularEndpoint = `${POPULAR_BASE_URL}&page=${this.state.data.currentPage + 1}`;

        const endpoint = this.state.searchTerm ? searchEndpoint : popularEndpoint;

        dispatch(fetchMovies(endpoint, 'search'));
    }
}
```

Also, could anyone confirm for me from what you see within the action creator? Is there any reason to create a reducer for this action creator? I don't seem to see any reason for one since it's not used to change the state but I'd like others opinion of that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `redux-thunk`, the function you return from an action creator can have two arguments, the second one being a function that gives you the current state:

```
export const loadMoreMovies = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    const searchEndpoint = `${SEARCH_BASE_URL}${state.searchTerm}&page=${state.data.currentPage + 1}`;
    const popularEndpoint = `${POPULAR_BASE_URL}&page=${state.data.currentPage + 1}`;



    const endpoint = state.searchTerm ? searchEndpoint : popularEndpoint;

    dispatch(fetchMovies(endpoint, 'search'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why using getState would be considered bad practice for any reason?